# Image textures not working in Cycles

Tags: textures, blender

I bought a fully textured .3ds model to play around with in Blender. Everything works perfectly in the regular Blender Render engine but when I bring it into Cycles the image textures disappear so the model is just white. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem is cycles, and internal are very different, in the sense of materials, lighting, and pretty much anything having to do with pictures and color. When you drop it into cycles, cycles uses a different way of UV mapping, so you can use the image and model still you just have to re-UV map, and texture it, but in the cycles way of course. I can't remember all the steps right now but here is a good video for that: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ck_DCf21KMM